# JavaScript alert() advancing system time by 12ms

Tags: javascript, alert

Here's a strange one:

I was working on synchronizing a JavaScript timer with a remote server and noticed my timer (based on the `Date()` object) was gaining about 12ms relative to my remote server on each page refresh. I narrowed it down to the JavaScript `alert()` function.

I created the following test and verified with 2 synchronized clocks that my system time will advance 1 second every 83-84 page refreshes. Has anybody seen this before?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('hello');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using IE7 on XP SP3. Please tell me I'm not just going crazy!

---

**EDIT:**

I'm really not concerned about the accuracy of javascript timers. The real issue is that the JavaScript `alert()` function call is advancing my actual system time by 12ms.

Comment: Does this happen to be on a virtual machine?

Comment: You know that there is a delay between sending and receiving data from a server?

Comment: @alopix There's no send and receive in his example, this is a pretty interesting bug if true.

Comment: @alopix, did you read the question or look at the code?

Comment: @Derek: Did you try this experiment on a different computer?

Comment: @Daniel: Not yet. I'm at work right now, so I'll have to try at home with different browsers and operating systems.

Comment: Try refreshing it 88 times during a lighting storm.

Comment: Just tried this (IE7, XP SP3) and to my surprise, get the same results - system time is advanced with each alert. Not sure if it's by the same amount as the OP as I didn't count the refreshes, but it definitely advances.

Comment: How do you know it's the system clock advancing and not the rest of the universe losing time?

Comment: @Jason: Maybe the javascript alert causes my computer to approach the speed of light?

Comment: If it's the system time advancing, or the rest of the universe losing time, this looks like one of the weirdest IE bugs ever seen.

Comment: Definitely one of the most "interesting" IE bug I've ever seen.

Comment: Did you try running the test 100000 times, and see if the time difference is 1200 seconds (20 minutes)?

Comment: Did you try synchronizing the clocks, and then, *not really do anything*, or at least browse it like you would normally do, and then testing how far they're out of sync?  (You know, as a control.)

Answer (score 2):

Well,

most likely you are crazy, since you are counting on JavaScript timers to be precise.

This explains a lot of that: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Comment: But the OP claims that his *system time* gets altered. This is something else, isn't it?

Comment: What I'm talking about isn't a delay in my javascript timer -- My actual system time is being modified by the execution of the alert() function. I've refreshed this page a couple hundred times and now when I pull up my system clock it is 5 seconds ahead of my watch that I had just synchronized with my system.

Comment: @Derek: I always knew that JavaScript is **evil** ;) (*sorry for not providing a more useful comment*).